# Convert any currency to USD using Python

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I have a dataframe
`rates=`

```
  from_currency  to_currency     exc_rate   date
  CAD               USD           13    1/1/2020
  AED               USD           50    2/1/2020
  GBP               USD           36    2/1/2020
  INR               USD           72    1/1/2020
```

and another dataframe
`company=`

```
  currency         value            company    date
  CAD               10              A       1/1/2020
  AED               10              B       2/1/2020
  GBP               10              C       2/1/2020
  INR               10              A       1/1/2020
```

Now I want to convert currency of each company to USD on a specific date based on the `exc_rate` column in the `rates` dataframe.

So the output dataframe would look like

`company=`

```
  currency         value            company    date         converted
  CAD               10              A       1/1/2020          130
  AED               10              B       2/1/2020          500
  GBP               10              C       2/1/2020          360
  INR               10              A       1/1/2020          720
```

Comment: What does the date have to do with anything?

Comment: @user17242583 Exchange rates vary, so OP wants to look them up on the specific day. [I thought OP replied to you already but apparently not.]

Answer (score 0):

First convert `rates` to a lookup table:

```
exc_rate = rates.set_index(['from_currency', 'to_currency', 'date'])['exc_rate']
```

```
from_currency  to_currency  date    
CAD            USD          1/1/2020    13
AED            USD          2/1/2020    50
GBP            USD          2/1/2020    36
INR            USD          1/1/2020    72
Name: exc_rate, dtype: int64
```

Then for each row in `company`, get the corresponding rate, multiply by the `'value'`, and assign the result to `'converted'`:

```
def convert_to_usd(row):
    return row['value'] * exc_rate[row['currency'], 'USD', row['date']]
company['converted'] = company.apply(convert_to_usd, axis=1)
```

```
  currency  value company      date  converted
0      CAD     10       A  1/1/2020        130
1      AED     10       B  2/1/2020        500
2      GBP     10       C  2/1/2020        360
3      INR     10       A  1/1/2020        720
```

Comment: P.S. I'm pretty new to Pandas myself, so this might not be the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: @user It works perfectly with the example you gave. What errors are you getting?

Comment: i have added the error in the questoin, please have a look

Comment: @user Um, the question hasn't changed, and you submitted an edit to my answer which I rejected.